# Match values between two files awk

Tags: awk, csv

I want to compare the first columns from two files. If there is a match, export the corresponding values of the second file to the first file.

```
File 1
username, fields

File 2
username, other_fields

Output File
username, fields, other_field if there is a match else blank
```

I have used this code but the output file is blank

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' File2 File1
```

Comment: Your example data seems to be made up from comma-separated fields, but your `awk` code is parsing whitespace-separated fields.  Showing some actual data would help us understand what your code is doing wrong.  Also, what does "else blank" mean? If if there is no match between the files on the 1st field, should there be a blank line in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
join -t, -a1 <(sort -k1,1 -t, file1) <(sort -k1,1 -t, file2)
```

or `csvjoin` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
csvjoin --left -H -c a file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea is to get an output.csv file instead to print the result, do you know how to do ?

Comment: @arnaudjnn. Just redirect the output to your output file.

Comment: If I do : awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > output.csv I dont get what expected. Is it because my two files are ";" separated ?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > output.csv

FS=OFS=";" sets the input and output FieldSeparator to ";"

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' file1 file2 > output.csv
```